# power shell how to treat \n as literal regunescape

Tags: regex, powershell, newline

I'm un-escaping some strings with power shell and ran into a little problem. How can i unescape the strings while treating \n as literal.

eg

```
$str = "\n\n\u041c\n\u0435";

[regex]::Unescape($str)
```

result:

```
newline
newline
M
E
```

intended result

```
\n\nM\ne
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can't exclude anything from the `Unescape` method, I would simply let it unescape everything and place the literal newlines back:

```
[regex]::Unescape($str).Replace("`n", '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

While [iRon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61570435/9898643) is the easiest I think, you could use a helper function to just replace the unicode literals in the string.

Something like:

```
function Convert-UnicodeLiterals {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [string]$Text    
    )
    $regex = [regex] '(?i)\\u[0-9a-f]{4}'
    $match = $regex.Match($Text)
    while ($match.Success) {
        $codePoint = [int]($match.Value -replace '^\\u', '0x')
        $Text = $Text.Replace($match.Value, [string][char]::ConvertFromUtf32($codePoint))
        $match = $match.NextMatch()
    } 

    $Text
}

$str = "\n\n\u041c\n\u0435" | Convert-UnicodeLiterals
```

Result:

```
\n\nМ\nе
```